# Android listview: Different colours in Items and SubItems?

Tags: android, android-listview

Is it possible to an item in a list view as one colour and its sub items as a different colour?

I am creating a game (times tables quiz game) in which the question and the answers the user gives as well as the correct answer are transfered through to a list view. e.g.:

Item- "7 x 5= (user answer)"
subitem- "(correct answer)"

I want the question i.e. "7x5" to be in black, the user answer to be green if correct and red if not correct. And also the correct answer to always be green

Activity in which I wish to change the colours:

```
public class TestResults extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.testresults);

        ListView itemList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvRandomTestresults);

        //gets all necessary data from the previous activity
        int[] results = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("results");
        String[] questions= getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("Questions");
        int[] correctAnswer= getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("CorrectAnswer");

        ArrayList < HashMap <String, String> > list = new ArrayList < HashMap <String, String> > ();


        // loop to give list view
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {

            int userAnswer = results[i - 1];

            int expectedAnswer = correctAnswer[i-1];

            String userString = questions[i-1] + userAnswer;

            String expectedString = " " + expectedAnswer;

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put("user", userString);
            map.put("expected", expectedString);

            list.add(map);
        }

        String[] keys = {"user", "expected"};

        int[] ids = {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, keys, ids);

        itemList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }//onCreate end 


}//class end
```

XML corresponding to this activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView 
       android:id="@+id/lvRandomTestresults"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new layout file called `list_row.xml` to be the layout of the row of your list. Each row will have this layout, each one with two TextViews.

### list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_row.xml"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/questionLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/answer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/correct"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#00FF00"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And create a custom ArrayAdapter to manage your view's colors. Create this class as inner class or you can create in a separated file if you want.

### MyArrayAdapter.java

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>
{
    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mQuestionArrayList;
    int mLayoutResourceId;
    String[] mQuestionsArray;
    int[] mUsersAnswers;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questionsArrayList, String[] questionsArray, int[] usersAnswers)
    {
        super(context, layoutResourceId);
        mContext = context;
        this.mQuestionArrayList = questionsArrayList;
        this.mLayoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.mQuestionsArray = questionsArray;
        this.mUsersAnswers = usersAnswers;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mQuestionArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View row, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        HashMap<String, String> question = mQuestionArrayList.get(position);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

        // Here you will initialize the row layout, by inflating the xml file list_row.
        row = inflater.inflate(this.mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);

        // Here we initialize those two TextViews defined in the list_row layout.
        TextView questionTxtView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.question);
        TextView answerTxtView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.answer);
        TextView correctAnswerTxtView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.correct);

        questionTxtView.setText(mQuestionsArray[position]);
        answerTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(mUsersAnswers[position]));
        correctAnswerTxtView.setText(question.get("expected").toString());

        // This is just a pseudo code to show you when and how to set the colors of
        // the TextView programatically.
        if(mUsersAnswers[position] != Integer.parseInt(question.get("expected").toString()))
            answerTxtView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        else
            answerTxtView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

        return row;
    }
}
```

And in your Activity's `onCreate()` method, you should have a `ListView` object and set the your custom array adapter (defined above as example) to your `ListView` this way:

### Your onCreate() method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView itemList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvRandomTestresults);

    //gets all necessary data from the previous activity
    int[] results = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("results");
    String[] questions= getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("Questions");
    int[] correctAnswer= getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("CorrectAnswer");

    ArrayList< HashMap <String, String> > list = new ArrayList < HashMap <String, String> > ();

    // loop to give list view
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        int userAnswer = results[i];

        int expectedAnswer = correctAnswer[i];

        String userString = questions[i] + " " + userAnswer;

        String expectedString = "" + expectedAnswer;

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        map.put("user", userString);
        map.put("expected", expectedString);

        list.add(map);
    }

    // Instantiate your custom array adapter
    MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_row, list, questions, results);

    // Here you set the custom adapter to your ListView.
    itemList.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

---

**I tested the code with fictional values, and the result below was retrieved from the code written in this answer.**
[image]

---

**Let me know if you have more doubts.**

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I have an idea what you mean, however my code is quite different so its hard to relate it, I have posted my code in my latest edit, thanks!

Comment: @RNI2013 I've updated my answer to fit your problem. You still can send an ArrayList with your HashMap and retrieve its values in the MyArrayAdapter Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, However what I was trying to achieve was to get the question i.e. "7x5=" all in black, then the user answer in green/red dependent on if its correct, then the correctAnswer below always in green. Is this still possible?

Comment: @RNI2013 indeed it is.

Comment: @RNI2013 updated the code of my answer. copy the xml and the adapter.

Comment: Thanks! In my code though the question and user answer arent seperate textviews, they are both in the one textview?

Comment: @RNI2013 you should make it in separated `TextViews`. It's easier to manage and handle its behavior.

Comment: Thanks, will i have to change the code in any way? It doesnt seem to run!

Comment: @RNI2013 just create that XML file, also create the `MyArrayAdapter` class, and change your **entire** `onCreate()` method with the `onCreate()` method I've posted here. Also if the question solves your problem please set it as the answer. =)

Comment: This has worked perfectly, thanks a lot for all your help and answering my many questions! lol

Answer (score 1):

In the code you give, you used a default adapter it's really not costumisable at all, you have to create you own adpater, so let's do it:

First of all you have to add an xml file to your layout folder represent one row in the listView:

## row.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/questionTV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/answerTV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

then you have to create you costum Adapter, so create new class and name it **MyAdapter** , put this code in it:

## MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

  private final Activity context;
  private final String[] questions;
  private final int[] answers;
  private final int[] rightAnswers;


  static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView text1;
    public TextView text2;
  }

  public MyAdapter(Activity context, String[] questions, int[] answers, int[] rightAnswers){
    super(context, R.layout.row, questions);

    this.context = context;
    this.questions= questions;
    this.answers= answers;
    this.rightAnswers= rightAnswers;
  }

 @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
      rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

      // configure view holder
      ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
      viewHolder.text1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.questionTV);
      viewHolder.text2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.answerTV);

      rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    // fill data
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

    String question = questions[position];
    int answer = answers[position];
    int rightAnswer = rightAnswers[position];

    //set Question in the text View with a BLACK backgroud color
    holder.text1.setText(question);
    //holder.text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    //set User Answer with GREEN backgroun if it's correct or RED if it s not
    holder.text2.setText(String.valueOf(answer));
    if(answer == rightAnswer){
       holder.text2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }else {
       holder.text2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    } 

    return rowView;
  }
}
```

---

finally you need to customise your activity with that:

## TestResults.java

```
public class TestResults extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.testresults);

        ListView itemList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvRandomTestresults);

        //gets all necessary data from the previous activity
        int[] results = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("results");
        String[] questions= getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("Questions");
        int[] correctAnswer= getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("CorrectAnswer");

        itemList.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, questions, results, correctAnswer));

    }//onCreate end 


}//class end
```

---

And this is a simple test if it's needed :)
[image]

Comment: you shouldn't have created a new answer for this. instead you should've edited your existing answer with your code.

Comment: also your xml layout has some errors, there is no `width` and `height` option, it's called `layout_width` and `layout_height`.

Comment: @rogcg something else?!!

Comment: Your XML still has some missing parts and also you are commiting some mistakes on your `ArrayAdapter`. But I'm not gonna correct it for you. You should know about what you are writing.

Comment: BTW you shouldn't post an answer if you are not sure about its result. You haven't tested your code and you don't know if it's gonna work. It's not good for the community.

Comment: maybe i didn't make a test because i was pretty sure of what i'm doing ;)
if you need a test i'll give you one!

Comment: I'm not asking anything. Your answer is not for me, but for the OP. If you think that it will raise your question's quality, go for it. That's what stackoverflow needs. =)

Comment: i know what stackoverflow needs ;) and if i wasn't sure of what i'm doing i'll not post it